# Path error despite correctly-changed working directory

Tags: r, visual-studio

I'm trying to run an R script that starts by loading an XLSX file. After using the "Run Source" command to run the script, I get the error:

```
Error: `path` does not exist: 'C:/Users/z8080/data/sheet.xlsx'
```

This probably comes from this line:

```
read_excel(here("data", "sheet.xlsx"), "STUDIESALL")
```

This happens despite me having changed the working directory to the script's location:

```
setwd('d:/work/projectName')
```

The above line is the first line in the script, and I also used it at the command line (terminal). I can verify - using `getwd()` - that the working dir has been changed correctly, but R still looks in `C:\Users\z8080`.

Also not helpful is to add this line at the start of the script:

`set_here(path = "d:/work/projectName", verbose = TRUE)`

Will I need to change some default path in Visual Studio, or some Windows env variable, or simply to change the working directory using a different command?

Comment: What command are you using to read the excel file in RStudio?

Comment: Have you checked if here::here() points to the correct path? It is hard to tell where the issue is since it depends on your overall project structure. I recommend you insert here::i_am('d:/work/projectName') at the top of your script as well.

Comment: @SEcker thanks! I added that line, but then I get `here() starts at C:/Users/z8080` and 
`Error: filepath must be a file or a relative path, not an absolute path.`

Comment: @SEcker I added a `set_here` at the start of the script, but it still doesn't help (see updated question)